# (Clarification) Object Pooling and Base Class Assignment( is this an Undefined Behavior?)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I'm trying to explore an old MMORPG Source to get a handle on how they "Used" to do things.
I've come across a code that did something like this.

Note: This is not the actual code but I've written something that mimics the original Codes logic.
EDIT: Note 2: the Pool Part of a Pool Class and I've not done this here to simplify things.

```
class VMAIN
{
public:
    int nVar1;
    int nVar2;
    VMAIN():nVar1(0),nVar2(0){;}
    virtual ~VMAIN (){;}
    void Reset()
    {
        nVar1=0;
        nVar2=0;
    }
    void Assign(const VMAIN& vSub)
    {
        *this = vSub;
    }
    VMAIN* GetMAIN(){return this;}
};
class VSUB: public VMAIN
{
public:
    float fVar1;
    float fVar2;
    VSUB():fVar1(0),fVar2(0){;}
    void Reset()
    {
        fVar1 = 0;
        fVar2 = 0;
    };
};
std::queue<VMAIN*> vecMain;
std::queue<VSUB*> vecSub;
VMAIN* NEW_VMAIN()
{
    VMAIN* pMain;
    if ( vecMain.empty() )
    {
        pMain = new VMAIN;
    }
    else
    {
        pMain = vecMain.front();
        vecMain.pop();
    }
    return pMain;
}
VSUB* NEW_SUB()
{
    VSUB* pMain = NULL;
    if ( vecSub.empty() )
    {
        pMain = new VSUB;
    }
    else
    {
        pMain = vecSub.front();
        vecMain.pop();
    }
    return pMain;
}
void RELEASE_MAIN(VMAIN* pMain)
{
    pMain->Reset();
    vecMain.push(pMain);
}
void RELEASE_SUB(VSUB* vSub)
{
    vSub->Reset();
    vecSub.push(vSub);
}
int main()
{
    std::queue<VSUB*>vSub;
    for ( int i = 0; i != 5 ; i++)
    {
        VMAIN* pMain = NEW_VMAIN();
        pMain->nVar1 = i+1;
        pMain->nVar2 = i+1;
        VSUB* pSub = NEW_SUB();
        pSub->Assign(*pMain);
        pSub->fVar1 = float(i)+0.5f;
        pSub->fVar2 = float(i)+0.5f;
        printf("Iteration: %d , nVar1 %d , nVar1 %d, fVar1 %.2f, fVar2 %.2f\n",i,pSub->nVar1,pSub->nVar2,pSub->fVar1,pSub->fVar2);
        vSub.push(pSub);
    }
    printf("\n Releasing \n \n");
    const int nSize = vSub.size();
    for ( int i = 0; i < nSize; i++)
    {
        VSUB* pSub = vSub.front();
        vSub.pop();
        printf("Iteration[Before]: %d , nVar1 %d , nVar1 %d, fVar1 %.2f, fVar2 %.2f\n",i,pSub->nVar1,pSub->nVar2,pSub->fVar1,pSub->fVar2);
        int j = i+10;
        VMAIN* pMain= NEW_VMAIN();
        pMain->nVar1 = j;
        pMain->nVar2 = j;
        if ( j  < 12 )
        {
            RELEASE_MAIN(pSub->GetMAIN());
            pSub->Assign(*pMain);
            printf("Iteration[After Replacing BASE]: %d , nVar1 %d , nVar1 %d, fVar1 %.2f, fVar2 %.2f\n",i,pSub->nVar1,pSub->nVar2,pSub->fVar1,pSub->fVar2);
        }
        else
        {
            RELEASE_MAIN(pMain);
            printf("Iteration[After Not Toching Base Values]: %d , nVar1 %d , nVar1 %d, fVar1 %.2f, fVar2 %.2f\n",i,pSub->nVar1,pSub->nVar2,pSub->fVar1,pSub->fVar2);
        }
        RELEASE_SUB(pSub);
        RELEASE_MAIN(pSub->GetMAIN());
        printf("Iteration[After Release]: %d , nVar1 %d , nVar1 %d, fVar1 %.2f, fVar2 %.2f\n\n",i,pSub->nVar1,pSub->nVar2,pSub->fVar1,pSub->fVar2);
    }
    int nSizeMain = vecMain.size(),nSizeSub = vecSub.size();
    printf("Size of vecMain %d, Size of vecSub %d\n",nSizeMain,nSizeSub);
}
```

The way I understood the code some values are calculated for the Base class and if it is acceptable it is assigned to the Derived class, and if not it's simply returned back to the pool.
I tried the code above and it does work, but is it simply working by Relying on undefined behavior or is it something usually,or used to be practiced?

Comment: `virtual ~VMAIN (){;}` - yuck. `virtual ~VMAIN() = default;`

Comment: As I said it's an old MMORPG source so i'm using the same conventions "They" did back when they wrote the code, this case it's VS2008 so, by using default the compiler will outright rejects it since by using default or =0, makes the base class abstract.

Comment: Using `= default;` does *not* make the base class abstract.

Comment: I know it doesn't, I'm just saying what the Compiler is outputting though. To be exact this.
`error C2259: 'VMAIN' : cannot instantiate abstract class`

Comment: `= default` is a C++11 thing. I doubt VS *2008* treats it correctly.

Comment: Are you talking about the `Assign` call? Why would that be UB?

Comment: No , I am worried about `RELEASE_MAIN(pSub->GetMAIN())` part of the code as far as my understanding of the Logic of the code. After `pSub->Assign(*pMain);`, `pMain` can be safely returned to the pool. but in the code In the original source, they are returning it to the pool separately. Hence the question. As far as my understanding goes it doesn't need to be released since VSUB has already inherited VMAIN.

Comment: As long as you don't delete it, there is no undefined behavior. I guess you could end up in a situation where with the same object in a situation where a call to `NEW_SUB` and a call to `NEW_VMAIN` refer to the same object, which would be pretty surprising, but that's still nowhere near undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the Clarification @Nelfeal, That cleared everything up. With your statement I assume the address that `RELEASE_MAIN(pSub->GetMAIN())` is inserting back to the pool is the Address of the Derived class `VSUB`. and as I tested printing out the address of `pSub->GetMAIN()` and `pSub` is returning the same address.